# How to get the number of lines executed in a method call in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, code-coverage

Lets say I make a method call and the method has 20 lines but only 6 lines are executed considering if else branches it takes. I wanted to know how to get this number of executed lines when a methodcall is made and also the number of lines inside the method. Is there any tracing class in C# that will help me do this? I wanted everything to be done programmatically. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing except profiling API which will give you that information. You can try looking at tools like NCover or such for out of process information capture about coverage.

Comment: You can find out the number of IL "lines", but the compiler may optimize things out, even methods in release mode. I'm not sure what use that information has for you?

Comment: @RonBeyer It's just an experiment thing. I just wanted to get a percentage of how much code has been executed after a series of method calls.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I will look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: why not depend on a code coverage tool

Comment: @CodeNameJack Code coverage tool can't be used because we are not using any testing framework and I have written my own testrunner. This is integration testing and is happening in a launched application. So I was hoping I can achieve code coverage programmatically.